# how to get npapi plugin for NPP_StreamAsFile

Tags: npapi

How can i get a npapi plugin. do i have to write for my own. or i can get it from somewhere. and please tell me that how to create a npapi.dll from npapi.h file. thanx.

or if anybody have any npapi.dll for NPP_StreamAsFile than please give me the link to download it and documentation for how to use it. thanx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.  Where to start?

You don't need an npapi.dll; npapi.h is used to implement an npapi plugin, but you don't link to npapi.h.  For a little more information about NPAPI plugins in general I recommend reading:

http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/

However, at the stage you're at, I would recommend against trying to do your own plugin and suggest you try utilizing FireBreath, which is a framework that simplifies a lot of the plugin creation process.  It has a good active development group that you can join if you get stuck.

http://www.firebreath.org